# How do I clear out a full JES2 spool?

Tags: zos

I'm trying to run my z/OS system, but I'm getting lots of the following messages:

```
$HASP355 SPOOL VOLUMES ARE FULL
```

How do I fix this?  I can't logon because the spools are full.

All I want if for my system to run properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need access to a z/OS Console.

If you don't care about any Output on the JES Spool then you can run the following command to purge it all:

```
$POJQ,JM=*
```

If you want to be more selective and perhaps try just deleting older stuff you can specify "age", for example to purge all output older than 30 days:

```
 $POJQ,JM=*,AGE>30
```

Adjust AGE up/down as needed/desired.

You could also change the "Job Mask" to be more specific about which jobs to purge. You can specify full jobnames or jobnames with a whildcard, for example, the following would purge only jobs having a prefix JOB12:

```
$POJQ,JM=JOB12*
```